# SQL query result is not showing in R odbc

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, odbc, rodbc

I am trying to run a simple query using R which is listed below. I am connected to odbc and it works fine with other queries.

```
MyQuery <- (dbSendQuery(conn, "Select count(ABC) FROM TABLE_1 GROUP BY YEAR(DATE_TIME)"))
```

When I run the above mentioned query in R environment it shows the below following result. The same query works fine in SQL Management Studio and return me the counted values.

```
<OdbcResult>
Rows Fetched:0 [incomplete]
Changed: 0
```

When I view it is shows

```
Name           Type                         Value
MyQuery        S4(odbc:odbcResult)    S4 Object of Class OdbcResult
```

Does this returns me the value location instead of actual values ?

Comment: While `dbGetQuery` is the recommended function, there may certainly be times when one should use `dbSendQuery` when retrieve data; if you read `?dbSendQuery`, it shows the call followed immediately by `dbFetch`. The help manual is your friend :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `dbSendQuery` which, as its name suggests, sends the query.  If you want to send and get the results in one command use `dbGetQuery`.  `dbSendQuery` is good if, either, you don't care about the results or if you know/suspect the results are going to be really big and you just want to fetch them in defined sized groups using `dbFetch` and then clearing the results using `dbClearResult`

In your example you could do:

```
MyQuery <- (dbSendQuery(conn, "Select count(ABC) FROM TABLE_1 GROUP BY YEAR(DATE_TIME)"))
querytable <- dbFetch(MyQuery, n=100) #assuming 100 or fewer results
dbClearResult(MyQuery)
```

or just

```
querytable <- (dbGetQuery(conn, "Select count(ABC) FROM TABLE_1 GROUP BY YEAR(DATE_TIME)"))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help and now I understand the difference between the two functions.